# alias of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I've been thinking about this for a while now, and I just can't make sense of what is going on here..  hopefully it's something simple?  In the output below I would expect a '41' in the first element of the second entry of 'c'.

```
>>> a = np.zeros(shape = (2,2))
>>> b = np.zeros(shape = (2,2))
>>> c = [np.array(x) for x in range(3)]
>>> c[1] = np.zeros(shape=(2,2,3))
>>> c[1][:,:,0] = a.view()
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> c
[array(0), array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

                  [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]]), array(2)]
>>> a[0,0] = 41
>>> a
array([[ 41.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.]])
>>> c
[array(0), array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

                  [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]]), array(2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you did:

`c[1][:,:] = a.view()`

Which makes a shallow copy.

If you did `c[1] = a.view()` instead you would see the behaviour you expected.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense because it's creating a slice right? (which is a copy)..  soo, this situation is actually something more like this (updated the question), so I can't just do the direct indexing on 'c'..

Comment: I think wim is still right. What you are doing is assigning `a.view()` to a slice of the array `c[1]`, modifying that array in-place. This copies the values from `a.view()` into `c[1]`. 

It's not possible to make a slice of one array act as a view into another array. numpy doesn't support this at all.